# PHP: how do i properly evaluate a nested variable variable in a loop?

Tags: php, variables, evaluate

ok.  here's the basics:

```
for ($k=1;$k<3;$k++) {
  ${'var'.$k} = 'foo';
} // so far so good

for ($j=1;$J<3;$j++) {    
  $dbq .= "stuff {$var{$k}} ";
} // problem here ^^  ^^
```

i'm looking for `$dbq` to render out to "`stuff foo stuff foo`".  but i'm not sure how to do this.  i can SET the variable in a loop no problem, but i don't know how to evaluate it out in a loop correctly.  PHP explodes when i try this.  i need the VALUES of the variable variable.  and its not even a true "variable variable" since there's no real referencing going on; not trying to mislead, i just don't know what else to call it...

and if there's a better way to do this, then by all means, enlighten me!  :P

TIA.  WR!

Comment: Instead of creating separate variables, you could store the `foo`-strings in an array: `$vars[] = 'foo';` and then in your second loop, do: `$dbq .= 'struff ' . $vars[$j] . ' ';`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the syntax in your output loop quite right, it's basically the same as the assignment loop. And you do need to use the same name as the loop variable (`j`, not `k`):

```
$dbq = '';
for ($j=1;$j<3;$j++) {    
  $dbq .= "stuff ${"var$j"} ";
}
echo $dbq;
```

Output:

```
stuff foo stuff foo
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/fvEnB)

Ultimately though the best solution for this is an array:

```
for ($k=1;$k<3;$k++) {
  $var[$k] = 'foo';
} // so far so good

$dbq = '';
for ($j=1;$j<3;$j++) {    
  $dbq .= "stuff {$var[$j]} ";
}
echo $dbq;
```

Comment: brilliant. thanks.  and i *would* normally use an array, but this is part of parsing an ungodly mess of a JSON dump, so i'm just brute-ing it into db query so i don't have to do any extra processing.  and, yeah, i borked the copy-paste on the variable.  thanks for the catch. :)

Comment: just coming back here to tell you what a relief this is for me.  thank you so much.  and this applies to @anant as well.  you guys... thank you.  this was the lynch pin for a lot of backed up work and i am so grateful.  too many long hours and not enough Monster in the can...  :D

Comment: @WhiteRau no worries at all - I'm glad we were able to help you out of a jam.

Answer (score 2):

2 issues:-

```
for ($j=1; $j<3; $j++) { //capital J needs to be small j
```

And change concatenation code like below:

```
$dbq .= "stuff ${'var'.$j} "
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/Q6arM

***Best approach is to use array:***

```
<?php

$var=[];
for ($k=1;$k<3;$k++) {
  $var[$k] = 'foo';
}

$dbq = ''; //define variable first
for ($j=1;$j<3;$j++) {
  $dbq .= "stuff $var[$j] "; //check syntax change
} 

echo $dbq;
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/kmlNX

***Even more simpler way:***

```
<?php

$var= array_fill(1,2,'foo');
$dbq = '';

foreach($var as $v){

    $dbq .= "stuff $v ";
}
echo $dbq;
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/n8Yct

Comment: ugh.  i see it now.  i was so close.  thank you so much.  :)  and, yeah, an array would be optimal, but this is part of chunking a godawful JSON mess into shape for a db query, so i'm trying to skip extra steps.  otherwise, yeah: arrays FTW.  and thanks for catcing my typos... i was tired.  :P

Comment: @WhiteRau  glad to help you:) . Now you can mark answer to close this question.